# Iterate through an array and return how many of each is present in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

So I have an array. The array has string values inside that can change each time:

```
var array = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
```

or sometimes:

```
var array = ['1','4','3','4','4'];
```

or even:

```
var array = ['1','3','3','4','4'];
```

How would I go about iterating through this array, figuring out which value is present the most and then displaying it. Also, how would I go about making it even smarter to understand that sometimes there is a tie between two values, as is the case in the last array above, and then displaying info notifying me that values "3" and "4" are tied... Or if there is no value that occurs more than once, thus displaying all values. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove duplicates from the array in addition to getting the value that occurs the most?

Comment: No, no removal, just searching through array and finding out the total amount present of each value.

Comment: Is this some sort of homework ?-)

Comment: It looked like those pesky questions CS teachers ask to their poor students :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = ['1','2','3', '3','4','5', '3', '4', '5', '5'],
l = array.length,
col = {},
current,
max = {cnt:0, values:[]};
while(l--){
  current = array[l];
  col[current] = (col[current] || 0) + 1;
  if(col[current] > max.cnt){
    max = {cnt:col[current], values: [current]};
  }else if(col[current] === max.cnt){
    max.values.push(current);
  }
}
console.log(
  max.cnt === 1 ? 
    'they are all different' : 
    max.values.join(',') + ' occured ' + max.cnt + ' times'
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach seemed to work the best. Is there a way to separate the two values if they're equal in to two different variables?

Answer (score 1):

```
function findMostFrequent(array) {
    // {
    //    "valueInTheArray": numberOfOccurances,
    //    ...
    // }
    var data = {};
    // for each value in the array increment the number of 
    // occurences for that value. the or clause defaults it to 0.
    $.each(array, function(i, val) {
        data[val] = data[val]++ || 1;
    });
    var answer = null;
    // for each value if the occurances is higher then to the counter.
    // then set that as the counter.
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         if (val > data[answer]) answer = key;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

You need two loops. One to count how many times each value occured. And one to find which one occured the most.

Optionally if you want to handle multiple high values then replace the second loop with this.

```
var answer = [null];
// for each value if the occurances is equal then add it to the array
// else if the occurance is higher then the current highest occurance.
// then set that as the current array of values.
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
     if (val === data[answer[0]]) {
          answer.push(key);
     } else if (val > data[answer[0]]) {
          answer = [key];
     }
}
return answer;
```

Comment: @GaryGreen data is an `Object` not an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks, this one worked great as well, the other just seemed to perform better. I appreciate everyone's feedback on this!

Comment: @Jim yes this one is a little slower. less manual array faffing though. Simply iterating over data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like this:

```
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
var counts = {};

for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    var num = arr[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
}
```

Now, you'll have an object that has a count of all the members in the array.

```
console.log(counts[5]); // logs '3'
```